# JSonStore Error with d.read

Tags: javascript, extjs

JsOnStore Coding

```
Ext.define('RouteSeqModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [{name: '_id', type: 'number'}, 'Route_Seq','Location_Name']
    });

    var RouteSeqStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
        model: 'RouteModelSeq',
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get-routeseq.php',
            api: {
                    create: 'insert-routeseq.php',
                    //read: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=read',
                    update: 'update-routeseq.php',
                    //destroy: 'http://visual04/ModuleGestion/php/Pays.php?action=destroy'
                },
            actionMethods: 'POST',
            extraParams: {
                    '_id' : '0',
                },  
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                //idProperty: '_id'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                //id: '_id'

             }
        }
    });
```

this is the combo box when selected changed then pass the extraparams to get the data and show at grid panel

```
xtype: 'combobox',
                    width: 191,
                    store: RouteNameStore,
                    displayField : "Route_Code",
                    fieldLabel: 'Route Code',
                    labelWidth: 70,
                    allowBlank: false,
                    editable: false,
                    listeners: {
                                    select: function( combo, records, eOpts ) {
                                    console.log("Combo selected _id : "+records[0].get('_id'));
                                    RouteSeqStore.load({
                                                params:{
                                                    _id: records[0].get('_id')
                                                }
                                            });
                                    }
                                }
```

and get-routeseq.php get work fine, this is firebug return JSON data from get-routeseq.php

```
[{"Route_ID":"1","Route_Seq":"1","Route_LocationID":"1","_id":"1","Location_ID":"1","Location_Name":"TRY","AddBy_ID":"2"},  
{"Route_ID":"1","Route_Seq":"2","Route_LocationID":"2","_id":"2","Location_ID":"2","Location_Name":"ABC","AddBy_ID":"2"}]
```

all working fine, but firebug with this error

```
TypeError: d.read is not a function


...f(p==k){if(a+E+l.width>(O>=0?u.x+u.width-b:b-u.x)){p=M}}else{if(a+E>l.width){p=k...
```

why?

Comment: When I have an error I can't figure out I try running the same app in both browsers (Chrome and Firefox) usually message errors are different and give more information about what could be wrong.

Comment: I would also try to isolate the problem by loading the store independently to validate it gets loaded properly to know if the problem is in the store or the definition on the combo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `model: 'RouteModelSeq',`

with `model: 'RouteSeqModel',`